# http://localhost:8080/ points to firefox installation directory C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox

Tags: firefox, webserver, http, localhost

When I type `http://localhost:8080/`  in any of my windows browser, I see all the files listed in `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox` which is my Firefox installation directory. I am not sure which http server is it as I have not installed any webserver myself.

I want to know which http server is running? any suggestion how to detect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run command

```
netstat -a -o
```

you will see a PID of proccess which bind your port.
after that you can detect a name of proccess with process manager.

Comment: Thanks just found out the process id and from that I checked in Task manager that some time back I had downloaded tried to run mongoose http server http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/ . But it had failed to start so I was wondering. Thanks